# How capture the active url based in a substring without repetition?

Tags: delphi, ui-automation, delphi-10-seattle

I want capture the url of active window based in a substring and add to **`Memo`** only if **sActiveURL** is different of **sOldURL**.

The trouble in my code is that always is added to **`Memo`** the same url ignoring the verification `if sActiveURL <> sOldURL`.

How fix this?

*Main*:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tmr1: TTimer;
    mmo1: TMemo;
    procedure tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sActiveURL,sOldURL : string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Flag: Boolean;

implementation
uses
 UIAutomationClient_TLB, Activex, StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

function GetURL(hTargetWnd: HWND): string;
  function Enumerar(pParent: IUIAutomationElement; Scope: TreeScope; pCondition: IUIAutomationCondition): String;
  var
    found    : IUIAutomationElementArray;
    ALen     : Integer;
    i        : Integer;
    iElement : IUIAutomationElement;

    retorno: integer;
    value : WideString;
    iInter: IInterface;
    ValPattern  : IUIAutomationValuePattern;
  begin
    Result := '';
    Flag := false;
    if pParent = nil then
      Exit;
    pParent.FindAll(Scope, pCondition, found);
    found.Get_Length(ALen);
    for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
    begin
      found.GetElement(i, iElement);
      iElement.Get_CurrentControlType(retorno);
      if (
          (retorno = UIA_EditControlTypeId) or
          (retorno = UIA_GroupControlTypeId)
         ) then
      begin
        iElement.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_ValuePatternId, iInter);
        if Assigned(iInter) then
        begin
          if iInter.QueryInterface(IID_IUIAutomationValuePattern, ValPattern) = S_OK then
          begin
            ValPattern.Get_CurrentValue(value);
            Result := trim(value);
            Flag := true;
            Break;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      if not Flag then
      begin
        Result := Enumerar(iElement, Scope, pCondition);
      end;
    end;

  end;
var
  UIAuto      : IUIAutomation;
  Ret         : Integer;
  RootElement : IUIAutomationElement;
  Scope       : TreeScope;
  varProp     : OleVariant;
  pCondition  : IUIAutomationCondition;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    UIAuto := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
    if Succeeded(UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(hTargetWnd, RootElement)) then
    begin
      TVariantArg(varProp).vt    := VT_BOOL;
      TVariantArg(varProp).vbool := True;
      UIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_IsControlElementPropertyId,
                                     varProp,
                                     pCondition);
      Scope := TreeScope_Element or TreeScope_Children;
      Result := Enumerar(RootElement, Scope, pCondition);
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
sActiveURL := GetURL(GetForegroundWindow);
if sActiveURL <> sOldURL then
begin
if AnsiContainsText(sActiveURL, 'stackoverflow.com') then
   begin
     sOldURL := sActiveURL;
     mmo1.Lines.Add('['+sActiveURL+']<'+DateToStr(Date)+'>');
   end;
end;
end;
```

[*UIAutomationClient_TLB.pas*](https://pastebin.com/KmSmHiXr)

---

**EDITION:**

On debug i discovered that none value is attrib to `sOldURL` variable.

```
procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
 sActiveURL,sOldURL : string;
begin
sActiveURL := GetURL(GetForegroundWindow);
mmo1.Lines.Add('[sOldURL  =       '+sOldURL+'      ]');
mmo1.Lines.Add('[sActiveURL  =       '+sActiveURL+'      ]');
mmo1.Lines.Add('');
if sActiveURL <> sOldURL then
begin
if AnsiContainsText(sActiveURL, 'stackoverflow.com') then
   begin
     sOldURL := sActiveURL;
     mmo1.Lines.Add(sActiveURL);
     mmo1.Lines.Add('');
     mmo1.Lines.Add('');
   end;
end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged to see what is in sOldURL at time of comparison? (Hint - disable the timer at start of routine and re-enable at end to do debugging).

Comment: @Dsm, this is a great trouble, my code is right but is very strange that `<>` or even `=` fails.

Comment: Indeed. Which is why you need to debug. As it stands your code appears to be OK, so you need to find at why it isn't. The starting point is to make sure that sOldURL and sActiveURL actually contain what you expect. If they do not then you need to investigate why not.

Comment: What does `GetURL(GetForegroundWindow);` return if some other window than your browser, f.ex. your own application window, has focus? The content of your memo by any chance? Whos content changes for every timer tick, since you write to it? Just some speculation.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, my trouble is that none operator of comparation like `<>` or `=` is working with code of `Timer` by unknow reason.

Comment: I need that add url to `Memo` only if active url contains determinated substring and actual url is different of previous detected. In others words, should add url to `Memo` only 1 time to each detection of url containg the specified substring.

Comment: Stop whining about operators not working! That is simply not true. Pay attention to what @Dsm said about checking exact content of `sOldURL` and `sActiveURL`. In `Enumerar()` you are looking for an edit control (`UIA_EditControlTypeId`), probably in an attempt to get the content of the browsers address editor. But you will get any focused windows first edit control content. Either answer Dsm's comments or simply delete this question if you can't take note of the offered help.

Comment: @Dsm, i edited the question with the possible reason of this trouble.

Comment: Your edit does not correspond to your original post. In the original post sOldURL and sActiveURL were class variables, an so persistent. In your post they are local variables and to the comparison is invalid as they will be created and destroyed every time.

Comment: BTW this way of debugging is not good. Try to learn how to use the debugger. It is a lot faster.

Comment: @Dsm, the result is the same (with class variables or locals). Tested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is as I shortly described in comments and is visible when the focused window is not your browser, for example your applications wiindow with the `mmo1: TMemo`:

`GetForegroundWindow()` returns the window that has focus.

Your `GetURL(GetForegroundWindow)` searches for an edit control (UIA_EditControlTypeId), of the focused window, and finds your memo control and returns the content of the memo.

Further, if you change focus to your browser, its URL will be correctly recorded in the memo, and if you return focus to your application, the condition `if AnsiContainsText(sActiveURL, 'stackoverflow.com')` will be true.

You then write to the memo, adding what you think is a real URL, and then this will be repeated for every timer event.

You need to only check the real browser window (skip all other) for its current URL. Try this, if you are using IE, otherwise you must modify `FindWindow()`:

```
procedure TForm24.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var                //
  hIEWnd: HWND;    //
begin
  hIEWnd := FindWindow('IEFrame', nil);  //
  sActiveURL := GetURL(hIEWnd);          //
//  sActiveURL := GetURL(GetForegroundWindow);
  if sActiveURL <> sOldURL then
  begin
    if AnsiContainsText(sActiveURL, 'stackoverflow.com') then
    begin
      sOldURL := sActiveURL;
      mmo1.Lines.Add('[' + sActiveURL + ']<' + DateToStr(Date) + '>');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Modified lines are marked with //